# LINQ query... How to perform?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Say I got next sequence:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I need make next thing with Linq:

```
1,2;
2,3;
3,4;
4,5;
...
9,10;
```

Can't get it.

Comment: Why do you need to use LINQ to do this?

Comment: 'coz it's SQL data. I get it with EF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 var list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

 var result = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length - 1)
                        .Select(i => new[] {list[i], list[i + 1]});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_sequence.Take(high - low).Select(i => new []{i, i + 1})
```

In your case: low = 1, high = 10.

To test you can write

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Take(10 - 1).Select(i => new []{i, i + 1})
```

in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var res =
    Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(item => new[] { item, item + 1 });
```